# create dynamic tabs and use control of tabs in C#.net

Tags: c#, user-controls, dynamic-controls

I created one emulator for one device, so each time the user clicks on the button I am creating one new form, and each form represents new devices.

now I am looking for another option by which inside my main form I can create multiple tabs  (instead of multiple forms) which has controls like button, dropdown, text box, grid view.
and the user can navigate between tabs, create a new tab dynamically, use controls inside of the tab.

any suggestion ??

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the TabControl on my 'main form'. and added tab pages at runtime.

```
tabControl1.TabPages.Add("New Tab");
```

placed an entire form inside a tab control ...this code will create a new instance of a form and place it in the last tab of a tab control:

```
frmDevice dev = new frmDevice();
dev.TopLevel = false;
dev.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
dev.Parent = tabControl1.TabPages[tabControl1.TabCount - 1];
dev.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
dev.Show();
```

Reference :https://www.codeproject.com/Answers/5246227/Create-dynamic-tabs-and-use-control-of-tabs-in-csh#answer1